# Cluster analysis with daisy

Tags: r, cluster-computing, analysis, r-daisy

I'm trying to perform a Hierarchical cluster analysis with RStudio, by using the package `daisy`. This is my dataset:

```
data.frame':341 obs. of  28 variables:
$ Impo_Env : Ord.factor w/ 3 levels "Low"<"Med"<"High": 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 3 ...
$ ComparativePriority_IAS: Ord.factor w/ 3 levels "Low"<"Med"<"High": 3 1 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 ...
$ Strategy_Eradication: Ord.factor w/ 3 levels "No intervention"<..: 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 2 3 ...
$ Knowl_BiodivLoss: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Control_Trade: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Engagement_Retail: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Knowl_PastProj: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 ...
$ Priority_IAS: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Knowl_Eradic: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 ...
$ Alert_CFS: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 ...
$ Alert_Municipality: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Alert_Park: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 ...
$ Alert_Police: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Alert_Firemen: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
$ Supp_AuthorityIAS: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Knowl_Env: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Info_Tv: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 ...
$ Info_Web: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 ...
$ Info_Radio: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 ...
$ Info_Magazines: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 ...
$ Info_School: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
$ Blacklist: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Workshop: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 ...
$ SuppFin_FutProj: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Tourist_dummy: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 ...
$ Gender: Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 ...
$ logIASknown: num  2.89 2.94 2.89 2.56 3.14 ...
$ Age: int  20 41 14 10 26 33 19 59 23 16 ...
```

I would like to use the Euclidean distance with `daisy`, however when I run

```
daisy(fuu, metric = c("euclidean"), type=list(ordratio = c(1,2,3), asymm=c(4:24), symm=c(25,26)))
```

The output is not fine. Gower's distance is used instead of Euclidean distance:

> Warning message:In daisy(fuu, metric = c("euclidean"), type = list(ordratio = c(1,:with mixed variables, metric "gower" is used automatically

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As described in "Details" section within the documentation of the daisy function contained in the cluster package:

> The handling of nominal, ordinal, and (a)symmetric binary data is
>   achieved by using the general dissimilarity coefficient of Gower
>   (1971). If x contains any columns of these data-types, **both arguments
>   metric and stand will be ignored and Gower's coefficient will be used
>   as the metric**.

In other words, for euclidean metrics (distances as root sum-of-squares of differences) to be computed, input columns must be numeric (mode) variables (i.e. all columns when x is a matrix) and thus recognised as interval scaled variables, as opposed to *nominal* (columns of class factor) variables or *ordinal* (columns of class ordered) variables. Specifying variable type within the *type argument* does not change this fact.

Under these premises, and supposing it makes sense for all of your 28 variables despite some being qualitative binary, you might try converting them with `as.numeric` and proceed then, reason being: ***with mixed variables metric "gower" overrides being automatically used***.

Comment: the suggested **as.numeric** conversion of qualitative variables is for binary factors to be accepted by daisy in order to compute euclidean distances, which are otherwise dealt with by the Gower method.